# How to remove tooltip from Phone Number field in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, checkout

How to remove `tooltip` from `Phone Number` field in `checkout` page?

Comment: do you want to remove this tool tip which says " For delivery questions. "

Answer (score 0):

place this into your `checkout_index_index.xml` for shipping address. (close tags appropriately, I omitted them for display)
for billing address you need to create a plugin, see this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/170732/42007

```
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for me @steros answer didn't provide a useful solution. I found in this [stack overflow question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184916/magento-2-how-to-remove-tooltips-from-checkout-page) another XML example and it worked so I'm adding it here for reference.

The `item name="telephone"` element need to look like this

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
  <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
  </item>
</item>
```

As mentionned in the link above, this solution seems to work because the knockout template is expecting the tooltip to exist OR to be a boolean value set to true.

```
<!-- ko if: element.tooltip -->
    <!-- ko template: element.tooltipTpl --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```